# Reading from a file reads only the last line in python

Tags: python

I have a problem with python and file reading. When i'm running this code, it reads only the last line from the text file. This is the code:

```
with open("main.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("console.out(") and line.endswith(")"):
            if line.startswith("console.out(\"") and line.endswith("\")"):
                consoleFixWS = line.replace("console.out(\"", "")
                finalOutWS = consoleFixWS.replace("\")", "")
                
                print(finalOutWS)
```

The text file:

```
console.out("Test")
console.out("Test2")
```

It prints only "Test2" and I tried everything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you do `for line in f:`, `line` includes the trailing newline.

Comment: There's missing parameter in your `open()` method. Where's the `r` reading parameter?

Comment: @Dr.Xavier It's optional; if you omit it, `'r'` is assumed.

Comment: Oh yeah, I fixed it but it still doesn't work.

Comment: There could be trailing whitespace in your lines, try adding a `line = line.strip()` before the conditional

Comment: yeah. it works.

Comment: Just as nice as i thought it would be, thanks to all you people. thank you.

Comment: without you my dream wouldnt be possible.

Comment: thank you so much, so,so, much,

Comment: also help me with my c# code.

Comment: I need it too tho.

Comment: So so much I need it.

Comment: Thanker lanker you for la it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line actually ends with a `\n` newline character. If you run `line = line.strip()` before the conditional it will remove any leading and trailing whitespace.

```
with open("main.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith("console.out(") and line.endswith(")"):
            if line.startswith("console.out(\"") and line.endswith("\")"):
                consoleFixWS = line.replace("console.out(\"", "")
                finalOutWS = consoleFixWS.replace("\")", "")

                print(finalOutWS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is your `startswith`/`replace` is bugging. Try `re` module: very nice and flexible:

```
import re

regex = "console\.out\((?P<text>(.*))\)"
with open("main.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        search = re.search(regex, line)
        if search:
            text = search.group('text')
            finalOutWS = text.replace("\\", "")
            print(finalOutWS)
```

Works fine